# Can you create an Outlook rule that adds a custom header to all outgoing messages?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003, email-filter

I have an Exchange 2003 mail server.  There is a user account that is only used to send automated emails (such as when shipments arrive, etc).  I want to set the `X-Auto-Response-Suppress: ALL` header on all messages sent from this email address.  The goal is to suppress auto-responses such as Out-of-office replies, and this appears to be the correct way to go about it.

When I go to create a rule in Outlook (2003), it allows me to create a rule for all sent messages, but I don't see an option to add a custom header.  There is an option to "perform a custom action" but there are no options in there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803977/how-do-i-specify-x-headers-for-outgoing-emails-in-microsoft-outlook-2010

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - that's an interesting answer, but I would prefer to avoid 3rd party solutions, if my existing technology stack can already do it.

Comment: Well you can do it [via VBA](http://www.outlookcode.com/threads.aspx?forumid=5&messageid=27515), but probably not without 3rd party utilities since you're stuck on OL2003. Check out http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm